# Mysql and PHP encoding does not match

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have a problem with encoding of PHP and Mysql. The encoding of the html page & the php page is utf-8; database, table and column is utf8_unicode_ci. I use Punjabi Language that is an indic language. The text in the table in phpMyAdmin appears as `à¨‰à¨¸à¨¤à¨¤` when I insert values with a textbox and php. I tried using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFLIE`, but now the values appear correctly in phpMyAdmin but doesn't match with the encoding of the html page. They appear as `??????`. The encoding of the uploaded text file is UTF-8...

The encoding of the pages doesn't match. I want to use the encoding uploaded by the text file. But I am not able to figure it out.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a SQL query `CHARSET utf8` before issuing other commands. This will change the connection character set to UTF-8.

Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html